# post parameters to htaccess sef link

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have url for ex:

```
 http://www.demo.com/a/abcd
```

And I use this htaccess to post this url's values

```
RewriteRule ^a/(.*)$ /details.php?sef=$1 [L,NC]
```

But I need to get new parameters posted the url 
For ex:

```
 http://www.demo.com/a/abcd?id=123&qu=11
```

So how can I get the **id** and **qu** variables values via this url without do any changes in URL?

Comment: I don't see really the problem here? You can use just ```$_GET['id']``` and ```$_GET['qu']``` Or do you mean something like: ```RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ process.php?width=$1&height=$2&third=$3 [QSA,L]```so you can add multiple variables to the url

Comment: Give more information what  `sef` contains?
`var_dump($_GET['sef'])`

Comment: Yes Erik, thanks for your help.  I solve this issue with [QSA,L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Apache's docs on mod-rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> ### Modifying the Query String
>
> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can,
>   however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query
>   string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string
>   to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the
>   query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the
>   substitution string with just a question mark. To combine new and old
>   query strings, use the `[QSA]` flag.

Since, you are writing the query string in a rewrite, use the `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^a/(.*)$ /details.php?sef=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```